# Child Component of vuetify `v-tabs` returns offsetWidth as 0

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuetify.js

Here is the codepen that reproduces the scenario: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzqgJB

I have a `router-view` inside vuetify's `v-app`.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        {{$route.path}}
        <router-view/>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

The routing configuration is as follows:

```
const routes = [
    { path: '', component: tabsComponent, 
      children:[
        { path: '', component: component1 },
        { path: 'component2', component: component2 }
      ]
    },
]
```

I am using the `v-tabs` component of Vuetify to render 2 tabs that load `component1` and `component2` respectively.

```
var tabsComponent = Vue.component('tabsComponent',{
  components:{
    component2,
    component1
  },
  name:'tabsComponent',
  template: `
     <v-tabs>
        <v-tab to="/">Tab 1</v-tab>
       <v-tab to="/component2">Tab 2</v-tab>
       <v-tabs-items>
          <v-tab-item id="/">
            <component1></component1>
          </v-tab-item>
          <v-tab-item id="/component2">
            <component2></component2>
          </v-tab-item>
        </v-tabs-items>
     </v-tabs>
`,
   mounted(){
    this.$nextTick(()=>{
      console.log("tabs")
      console.log(this.$el.offsetWidth)
    })
  }
})
```

The problem I am facing is that, when `component1` is mounted, the `this.$el.offsetWidth` is returned as `0`.

```
  var component1 = Vue.component('component1',{
    name: 'component1',
      template: `
         <v-container fluid>John </v-container>
      `,
      mounted(){
        this.$nextTick(()=>{
          console.log("component1")
          console.log(this.$el.offsetWidth) // This is printed as 0
        })
      }
    })
```

I cannot figure out why the width is being returned as 0 even, though the parent components have non-zero offsetWidth.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some more info: It seems that when `component1` is mounted, both the `v-tab-item` have `display:none`. Since they are not in the DOM, there width is returned as 0. 
So, if some one can tell me how to fix my `v-tabs` with routing maintained correctly, this should get fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`mounted` hook in child component fired before mounted hook in parent**: mount hook in child, mount hook in parent and at last render to dom. So, in child component **you are two ticks away from render**. You can do what you want with two folded `$nextTick` or with `setTimeout` (setTimeout callback gets control after vue do all his stuff):

```
mounted(){
  this.$nextTick(()=>{
    this.$nextTick(()=>{
      console.log("component1")
      console.log(this.$el.offsetWidth)
    })
  })
}
```

or

```
mounted(){
  setTimeout(()=> {
    console.log("component1")
    console.log(this.$el.offsetWidth)
  })
}
```

Illustration from [Vue Parent and Child lifecycle hooks](https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f):

[image]

---

**update to your comment:**

Yes, you cant get `offsetWidth` of inactive tab with `display: none`. But offset of all tabs is equals to each other? Anyway, you can dynamically track active tab. Use `v-model` on your `tabsComponent` and add watch method in which you can get your metrics when tab is visible. Also you should add `ref` to both your components and inner containers (by setting ref name of component equals to tab path your can use `activeTab` to access active component inner refs).

In templates:

```
<v-container fluid ref="div">John</v-container>
# ...
<div id="component2" ref="div">Jinny</div>
# ...
<v-tabs v-model='activeTab'>
# ...
<component1 ref="/"></component1>
<component2 ref="/jinny"></component2>
```

In script:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    activeTab: null
  }
},
watch: {
  activeTab: function () {
    this.$nextTick(()=> {
      console.log(this.$refs[this.activeTab].$refs.div.offsetWidth) 
    })
  }
}
```

updated codepen with watch method: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qMeYGZ

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think using `setTimeout` makes more sense here, since, using `$nestTick` will require finding out  the level of nesting for the child component

Comment: This solution does not work for `component2`. Since vuetify adds `display:none` to the tab contents, I get `offsetWidth` as 0 for `component2`. I have updated the codepen to show this problem.

Comment: Thanks man. One last question: Is there any way to get the width inside  `component2` instead of the `tabs` componet. I know I can pass the width as a `prop` to `component2`. Do you have any other approach on your mind?

Comment: @AnkitKante i think prop is ok